Authorize_and_exchange_code failed error invalid_client Binance OAuth with Flutter
I’m working on integrating Binance OAuth authentication into my Flutter application but encountering a configuration issue
const String discoveryURL = 'https://accounts.binance.com/.well-known/openid-configuration';
const String binanceAuthorizationUrl = 'https://accounts.binance.com/oauth/authorize';
const String binanceTokenUrl = 'https://accounts.binance.com/oauth/token';
const String binanceIssuer = 'https://accounts.binance.com';

final List<String> scopeList = [
    "user:openId"
  ];

final AuthorizationTokenResponse? result = await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
      AuthorizationTokenRequest(
        dotenv.env['BINANCE_CLIENT_ID']!,
        dotenv.env['BINANCE_REDIRECT_URI']!,
        clientSecret: dotenv.env['BINANCE_CLIENT_SECRET']!,
        serviceConfiguration: AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
          authorizationEndpoint: binanceAuthorizationUrl,
          tokenEndpoint: binanceTokenUrl
        ),
        discoveryUrl: discoveryURL,
        scopes: scopeList,
        issuer: binanceIssuer,
        nonce: 'nonce',
      ),
    );

Here is the error
login error: PlatformException(authorize_and_exchange_code_failed, Failed to authorize: [error: invalid_client, description: null], null, null)

Solutions Tried:
Changed Client Secret:
I accessed the Binance Developer Portal and changed the "Client Secret" many times to see if it resolved the issue. Despite this, I’m still receiving the same error message.
Other Troubleshooting Steps:
Verified client id, client secret and redirect url.
Expected Outcome:
I expected that changing the "Client Secret" would resolve the issue and allow me to receive the "Access Token" successfully. However, despite multiple attempts and changes, I continue to encounter the same error.
Additional Issue:
When I added "create:apikey" to the scopes, I received the following error:
PlatformException(authorize_and_exchange_code_failed, Failed to authorize: [error: invalid_scope, description: OAuth 2.0 Parameter: scope], null, null)

Scope Field in Binance Developer Account:
I've also noticed that the scope field in the Binance Developer account is not editable. This might be related to the issue, but I haven't found any documentation or settings to adjust it.
Question:
What could be causing the "invalid_client" error in my Binance OAuth integration, and are there other steps I can take to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Have you tried playing around with the scopes? I see binance documentation has create:apikey in the list as well. https://developers.binance.com/docs/login/app-integration
